# Understanding how to send dojo.store.memory datatype to the server

Tags: javascript, json, dojo, dgrid

I am new to using **Dojo framework**. I have implemented **dgrid** for collecting data and this works great for storing, querying, updating and deleting data from the client side during data entry. However once the **dojo.store.memory** data type has data i would like to use an **ajax** request to post the **dojo** object to the server.

I would like to post the data to the server in json format however i am unable to convert the object (*myStore*) to json string. Under is what i have attempted thus far:

**JavaScript function**

```
function SendForm(){
  var jsonIdObj = JSON.stringify(myStore);              

dojo.xhrPost({
   url:'processData',
   form:dojo.byId('myForm'),
   postData:jsonIdObj,
   success: function(){
        console.log('success');
    },
   error: function(){
    console.log('error occured');
    }
   }); 
}
```

**Data Store**

```
 var myStore = new dojo.store.Observable(new Memory({data: data, idProperty:"typeId"}));
```

**Data**

```
var data = [{ id:"1",age:"33",idtype:"1" ,first_name: "Edward", surname: "Davis" },
             { id:"2",age:"41",idtype:"2" ,first_name: "Lewis", surname: "Holl"},
             { id:"3",age:"59",idtype:"3" ,first_name: "Fred", surname: "James"}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you want to be stringifying `store.data`, not `store` itself.  `dojo/store/Memory` maintains the data itself in the `data` property of the store.

Secondly, you probably don't want to specify both `form` and `postData` to your XHR call - you probably just want `postData` in this case.  When `form` is specified to `dojo.xhrPost`, it gets converted into an object to pass to `postData` anyway.

Thirdly, if you're using Dojo 1.8 or newer, you should consider using the new [`dojo/request` API](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request.html).

Comment: Thanks again would you be able to point me to an example of how I can post 'data' when I click the next button on a wizard form. I know I have to attach a function to the passFunction in the wizard pane